# Trying to find the intercept between two sine waves

Tags: equation-solving

Want to know the value for `t` in the equation:

```
0.5sin((pi t)/5)=0.1sin((pi t)/4)
```

Comment: Which intercept? There are infinitely many.

Answer (score 2):

For illustrative purposes:

```
Plot[{0.5 Sin[Pi x/5], 0.1 Sin[Pi x/4], 
  0.5 Sin[Pi x/5] - 0.1 Sin[Pi x/4]}, {x, -1, 7}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[rt = ({u, 0.5 Sin[Pi u/5]} /. 
       NSolve[0.5 Sin[Pi u/5] == 0.1 Sin[Pi u/4] && 0 < u < 2 Pi, 
        u])], Text[Framed[rt], rt[[1]], {0, -4}, 
    Background -> White]}, GridLines -> {{rt[[1, 1]]}, None}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]